# adobe flex air file preview

Tags: apache-flex, air

We have an AIR application which connects to a WAMP server.
We support tiff images currently. We have a neat feature of previewing 
a tiff image( uses a URLLoader to read the bytes and opens the image in a popup)
We want to extend this preview feature to other types of files too like "pdf", 
"doc", "movie file" etc.

Please let me know how can we achieve this in Adobe AIR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.appfoundation.com/blogs/giametta/2009/04/14/render-pdf-in-adobe-air-with-pdf-scaling/

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1375018

http://coenraets.org/blog/2009/11/open-in-excel-another-air-2-mini-sample/

also new docs are zip files, so google for AIR ZIP reader and then get RFC from MS for doc, and have a fun)